# systemctl: Not enough space for hibernation

Tags: manjaro, hibernate

I'm trying to hibernate my Manjaro system using a swap partition. I have followed all the steps on [the wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Swap), but running `systemctl hibernate` results in the following output:

```
Call to Hibernate failed: Not enough swap space for hibernation
```

Using swapon, here is my output:

```
NAME      TYPE       SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda5 partition 18.8G   0B   -2
```

The [wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Swap) says for 12GB RAM, 15-24GB swap space is required.

Is there something I'm doing wrong/haven't done?